# Alternative solution for using triggers

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a Table that has his PK as a FK in two other tables.
I want when I delete a record from this table to delete records from the other tables based on the deleted row.
I know that there is a solution which is using triggers, and here is mine:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trig_Supp
    ON T_SALARIE
    FOR DELETE
AS
    DELETE FROM T_EVOLUTION
    WHERE Matricule = SELECT Matricule FROM deleted

    DELETE FROM T_EVALUATION
    WHERE Matricule = SELECT Matricule FROM deleted

GO
```

but our teacher told us to search for another solution which can do the same as this trigger does, but I couldnt find anything on the internet.

so is there really another solution to do that ?

Comment: have you read about cascade delete, http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php

Comment: and your trigger isn't quite correct since sql server doesn't fire them for each row but for each statement. your trigger would fail if someone deletes more than 1 row with one statement

Comment: Agreeing with previous comments, but also: Not to mention that if the FKs have actually been set up, this trigger won't work since constraint checks would happen (and prevent the first delete from ever occurring) well before this trigger (would have) fired.

Answer (score 2):

So what you're looking for is anything that will automatically handle the cascading deletes regardless of what kind of query was used to delete it.

As others already commented, the correct option would be to use delete cascade foreign keys, since clearly there's an implied foreign key connection there anyway. Also like Damien_The_Unbeliever said, without a such a constraint like that you could never remove the parent row without first removing the referencing child rows.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `OUTPUT` clause to capture deleted rows and then match and delete from your secondary tables. See BOL [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx).

The advantage of this is it will handle multiple rows.

Comment: The OP said he needed a solution that mimics triggers. On that note, changing every single query that deletes data is probably not an option, but instead you'd have to have the DB objects configured in a way that handles all this automatically whenever any query deletes the data.